# Installing Latex Packages in TexLive/TexStudio

Tags: latex, texlive

I am using TexLive and TexStudio, and am trying to install the bbm and physics latex packages. I have followed the instructions from this page: https://scholar.princeton.edu/scuellar/blog/2014/02/adding-new-packages-latex, yet when I try to use these packages, I get messages like "File `bbm.sty' not found. \RequirePackage". Does anyone know what the issue might be here? I am using Ubuntu 18.04, TexStudio 2.12.6, and tex 3.14159265 and kpathsea 6.2.3 for TexLive.

Answer (score 4):

If understand you correctly, you need single file `bbm.sty` - it is located in [`texlive-fonts-extra` package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=bionic&arch=any&mode=exactfilename&searchon=contents&keywords=bbm.sty).

Install it with:

```
sudo apt-get install texlive-fonts-extra
```

and then compile your TeX document.